# Elements overflowing from line

Tags: html, css

I believe my understanding of positioning is causing me multiple issues:

1. *'Donate' in the navigation header keeps overflowing* and not staying inline. I have experimented with display:inline-block, but it still is not working. I am trying to ensure that the navbar elements are responsive to different-sized pages and stay in the same line.
2. *'Our work' section will not center in the middle of the page*, even when I tried margin:auto
3. Unable to align the  elements in the problem section correctly. I would like row2 to be 10% below row1, so it's like a 2x2 table configurement.

I've been struggling with this for a while, so if anyone has any ideas on how to solve any of these and suggestions moving forward - it would be well appreciated!

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

header{
  font-family:'Ubuntu';
  
}

body{
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  text-align: left;
} 

/* Header */

header{
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:122px;
  background:#FFFFFF;
  z-index:1;
    
}

.wrapper{
width:90%;
margin:0 auto;
}

.logo{
width:30%;
float: left;
text-align:left;
line-height: 122px;
  }


nav{
float: center;
line-height: 122px;

}

nav a{
font-family:'Ubuntu';
font-weight: 500;
font-size:calc(50px+1vw);
line-height: calc(23px+1vw);
text-decoration: none;
letter-spacing: 4px;
color:#616161;
padding: 20px 20px;

}

.links:hover {
  background:#F3EA65;
}

.CTA{
padding: 15px 100px;
border: none;
background: #F28A31 ;
border-radius: 15px ;
font-family: Ubuntu;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: calc(13px+1wv);
font-size: calc(20px+1vw);
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
letter-spacing: 0.5px;
display: inline-flex;
}

.CTA:hover {
  background-color: #F3EA65;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
} 

/*Our work*/

#ourwork{
background:#fff;
position:absolute;
width: 932px;
height: 92px;
top: 700px;
left: 50%;
padding:10px;
}

/*Problem section */

#problembackground{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 561px;
top:852px;
background: linear-gradient(90.14deg, #DE5135 -20.57%, #6975A7 88.83%);

}

#problemcontent{
position: relative;
top: 25%;
left:5%;
}

.row1{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
padding-right:10%
}

.row2{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
top:10%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="....">
        <img src="Home.png" alt="Logo" width="25%";>
        </a>
      </div>
        <nav>
          <a class="links" href="#">about</a>
          <a class="links" href="#">our team</a>
          <a class="links" href="#">who we help</a>
          <a class="links" href="#">get involved</a>
          <a href="#">
            <button class="CTA">Contact</button>
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <button class="CTA">Donate</button>
          </a>
        </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  
 <main>  
 <section>
      <div id="ourwork">
        <h4>OUR WORK</h4><br>
        <p id="largertext">
          Youth Housing Project Association Inc. (YHP) provides supported, unsupervised,<br> medium-term accommodation in Brisbane to young people aged from 16-21 years old<br> who are homeless or at risk of homelessness.  
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
  
    <section>
      <div id="problembackground">
        <div id="problemcontent">
          <h2 id="the problem">the problem</h2><br>
          <div id="p1" class="row1">
            <h3>1 in 5</h3>
            <p>young Australians report high levels of<br> psychological distress</p>
          </div>
          <div id="p2" class="row1">
            <h3>28 000</h3>
            <p>12 to 24-year olds are homeless on any given<br> night in Australia</p>
          </div>
          <div id="p3" class="row2">
            <h3>1 in 6</h3>
            <p>16 to 24-year olds live below the poverty line</p>
          </div>
          <div id="p4" class="row2">
            <h3>35%</h3>
            <p>of 16 to 24-year olds have experienced<br> domestic violence at home</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You should look into flexbox or grid to position things, and media queries to make them adjust to different screen sizes. There are better ways to do things now days!

Comment: yes, that's a good way, I recommend you learn mostly flexbox, meanwhile, I am preparing the code for the answer

Comment: also, ty for the clean commented code, rarely anyone does that these days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
}

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 122px;
}


/* Header */

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 122px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 122px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  line-height: 122px;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  text-align: right;
}

nav a {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: calc(50px+1vw);
  line-height: calc(23px+1vw);
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #616161;
  padding: 20px 20px;
}

.links:hover {
  background: #F3EA65;
}

.CTA {
  padding: 15px 50px;
  border: none;
  background: #F28A31;
  border-radius: 15px;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: calc(13px+1wv);
  font-size: calc(20px+1vw);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.CTA:hover {
  background-color: #F3EA65;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

main,
section {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}


/*Our work*/

.ourworksec {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 100px 25px;
}

#ourwork {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 620px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}


/*Problem section */

h2#theproblem {
  padding: 20px;
}

#problembackground {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 100px 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(90.14deg, #DE5135 -20.57%, #6975A7 88.83%);
}

#problemcontent {
  position: relative;
}

.row1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.row2 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .logo {
    width: 80px;
  }
  nav {
    width: calc(100% - 80px);
  }
  nav a {
    padding: 15px 10px;
  }
  .CTA {
    padding: 15px 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="....">
        <img src="Home.png" alt="Logo" width="25%" ;>
      </a>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <a class="links" href="#">about</a>
      <a class="links" href="#">our team</a>
      <a class="links" href="#">who we help</a>
      <a class="links" href="#">get involved</a>
      <a href="#">
        <button class="CTA">Contact</button>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <button class="CTA">Donate</button>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<main>
  <section class="ourworksec">
    <div id="ourwork">
      <h4>OUR WORK</h4><br>
      <p id="largertext">
        Youth Housing Project Association Inc. (YHP) provides supported, unsupervised,<br> medium-term accommodation in Brisbane to young people aged from 16-21 years old<br> who are homeless or at risk of homelessness.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="problembackground">
      <div id="problemcontent">
        <h2 id="theproblem">the problem</h2><br>
        <div id="p1" class="row1">
          <h3>1 in 5</h3>
          <p>young Australians report high levels of<br> psychological distress</p>
        </div>
        <div id="p2" class="row1">
          <h3>28 000</h3>
          <p>12 to 24-year olds are homeless on any given<br> night in Australia</p>
        </div>
        <div id="p3" class="row2">
          <h3>1 in 6</h3>
          <p>16 to 24-year olds live below the poverty line</p>
        </div>
        <div id="p4" class="row2">
          <h3>35%</h3>
          <p>of 16 to 24-year olds have experienced<br> domestic violence at home</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Mihir! I implemented your code for the navigation header and it worked great!

Answer (score 0):

1. Regarding this one you simply don't have enough space at certain window widths to display them all, so you need to make their sizes responsive. `@media` queries at certain widths is one option.
2. "Our work" is `absolute`ly `position`ed, which messes with things like `margin: 0 auto` to center things. In general you use `position: absolute` WAY too often. Honestly you could avoid it all together looking at your page so far. `position: absolute` is a pain to work with when you come back to your project at a later stage too.
3. Here your problem is that the third element is still on the same line because you set `display: inline-block`. You could wrap both rows each in another `div` (which are `display: block` by default). Also work with `margin-bottom` here in my opinion. You are making it way harder with the way you use several `position` properties.

Comment: dude, that's helpful, but you really should give him the code

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and suggestions - makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Here:  I removed the floats and used flexbox and grid
Quick note:  This website is not responsive, so pls open it in the full window not hte mini window. If you want a responsive site, dang man, that's a big request
Code:

```html
<body>
    <style>
        *{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

header{
  font-family:'Ubuntu';
  
}

body{
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  text-align: left;
} 

/* Header */

header{
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:122px;
  background:#ffffff;
  z-index:1;
    
}

.wrapper{
width:90%;
margin:0 auto;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}


.logo{


text-align:left;
line-height: 100px;
height: fit-content;
display: inline-block;
width: fit-content;
padding: 30px;
margin: 0px;
  }

  .logo image {

  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;

  }


.wrapper a{
font-family:'Ubuntu';
font-weight: 500;
font-size:calc(50px+1vw);
line-height: calc(23px+1vw);
text-decoration: none;
letter-spacing: 4px;
color:#616161;
padding: 20px 20px;

}

.links:hover {
  background:#F3EA65;
}

.CTA{
padding: 15px 100px;
border: none;
background: #F28A31 ;
border-radius: 15px ;
font-family: Ubuntu;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: calc(13px+1wv);
font-size: calc(20px+1vw);
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;
letter-spacing: 0.5px;
display: inline-flex;
}

.CTA:hover {
  background-color: #F3EA65;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
} 

/*Our work*/

#ourwork{
background:#fff;
position:absolute;
width: 932px;
height: 92px;
top: 700px;
left: 300px;
padding:10px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
}
#work{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center ;
}

/*Problem section */

#problembackground{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 561px;
top:852px;
background: linear-gradient(90.14deg, #DE5135 -20.57%, #6975A7 88.83%);

}

#problemcontent{
position: relative;
top: 25%;
left:5%;
}
#the-problem{

margin: auto;
width: 300px;
}

.row1{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
padding-right:10%;
margin: auto;

}

.row2{
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
top:10%;
margin: auto;
}
.problem{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    
}

li{
    list-style: none;
}

    </style>
    <header>
        <ul class="wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="....">
            <img src="/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="25%";>
            </a>
          </div>
          
          <li>  <a class="links" href="#">about</a> </li>
          <li>  <a class="links" href="#">our team</a> </li>
          <li>  <a class="links" href="#">who we help</a> </li>
          <li>  <a class="links" href="#">get involved</a> </li>
          <button class="CTA">Contact</button>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
            <button class="CTA">Donate</button>
          </a>
           
      
        </ul>
    </header>
    
   <main>  
   <section id="work">
        <div id="ourwork">
          <h4>OUR WORK</h4><br>
          <p id="largertext">
            Youth Housing Project Association Inc. (YHP) provides supported, unsupervised,<br> medium-term accommodation in Brisbane to young people aged from 16-21 years old<br> who are homeless or at risk of homelessness.  
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
    
      <section>
        <div id="problembackground">
          <div id="problemcontent">
            <h2 id="the-problem">the problem</h2><br>
            <div class="problem">
            <div id="p1" class="row1">
              <h3>1 in 5</h3>
              <p>young Australians report high levels of<br> psychological distress</p>
            </div>
            <div id="p2" class="row1">
              <h3>28 000</h3>
              <p>12 to 24-year olds are homeless on any given<br> night in Australia</p>
            </div>
            <div id="p3" class="row2">
              <h3>1 in 6</h3>
              <p>16 to 24-year olds live below the poverty line</p>
            </div>
            <div id="p4" class="row2">
              <h3>35%</h3>
              <p>of 16 to 24-year olds have experienced<br> domestic violence at home</p>
            </div>
        </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I hope you like it coz I literally did this during school

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Will definitely start to implement Flexbox now :)